# Repeating Detail b section without effecting Details a and Details c in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010, crystal-reports-8.5

I have two temp-tables order and items. Single order may contain more than one item.
My report is like below

```
Detail a
Order1   Order type
Detail b
Item1    itemname
```

When an order have more than two items then item section should repeat until the end of the items for that particular order like

```
Detail a
Order1   Order type
Detail b
Item1    itemname
Detail b
Item2   itemname
Detail b
Item3    itemname ……..
```

But I am getting as

```
Detail a
Order1   Order type
Detail b
Item1    itemname
Detail a
Order1   Order type
Detail b
Item2   itemname
```

I want to do it in section expert only without any stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Use two reports in the report.

```
1. In detail A use first sub report
2. In detail B use second sub report.
```

Dont place any columns in the report only columns should be placed in sub report.

Comment: In one report I want display all the details( it is a situation that we don't want use sub report).

Comment: If you don't want to use sub report why don't you try creating groups for order and ITem